# Adding the values of a varying number of XML Tags to an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML file:

```
<productsList>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 1</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 2</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 3</name>
    </product>
</productsList>
```

This file is being given to me by a server. The response from the server varies depending on certain conditions so I cannot control what the server outputs. Here is how I normally get the data from inside an xml doc:

```
var dataFromXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('someTagName')[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
// goes into xmlDoc which is a xml file in string form then finds the fictitious tag someTagName and finally finds the node value.
```

What is the best way to make an array with the values of the name tag included keeping in mind that there will be a varying number of product tags?

Comment: Can you add some sample of what you expect to get? It is a little unclear right now

Comment: Sure, I would like to get an array with Product Name 1, Product Name 2 and Product Name 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with a selector that requires the parent to be a `product` element. And `Array.from` can be used to map that to the text contents:

```
var names = Array.from(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("product > name"), 
                       node => node.textContent);
```

Demo:

```js
const xmlstr = "<productsList><product><name>Product Name 1</name></product><product><name>Product Name 2</name></product><product><name>Product Name 3</name></product></productsList>";
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlstr,"text/xml");
const names = Array.from(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("product > name"), node => node.textContent);

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use DOMParser and use standard DOM methods like querySelectorAll. Ten because we are receiving a NodeList we need to trasform it to standard array to use map function on it to get proper data.
Here is working solution:

```js
const xml = `<productsList>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 1</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 2</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Product Name 3</name>
    </product>
</productsList>`;


parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
var names = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("name")].map(item => item.innerHTML)
                      
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Yep +1 from me, you were first :) I am always late :D